# shinydashboard header dropdown add group links

Tags: html, css, r, shiny, shinydashboard

I want to put multiple links within a dropdown menu in the header panel, but now I can only create it with a flat horizonal layout through tags$li, while I want a vertical grouped dropdown menu.

A minimal repeatable code is as below, I means I want to put the linkA and linkB under grouplinkAB, and users can open one of them in a new window. It may be achieved with dropdownMenu(type='notifications',...) as in the code, but I do not know where to put the group name of "grouplinkAB", and which can not open a new window when clicking on the link, also I have to hide the text "You have 2 notifications", so I want to achieve it with  tags$li and tags$ul, but I have little knowledge on HTML, any help will be appreciated.

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)

runApp(
  shinyApp(
    ui = shinyUI(
      dashboardPage(
        dashboardHeader(title='Reporting Dashboard',
                        tags$li(class="dropdown",tags$a("grouplinkAB",href="http://stackoverflow.com/", target="_blank")),
                        tags$li(class="dropdown",tags$a("linkA",href="http://stackoverflow.com/", target="_blank")),
                        tags$li(class="dropdown",tags$a("linkB",href="http://stackoverflow.com/", target="_blank")),
                        dropdownMenu(type='notifications',
                                     notificationItem(text='linkA',href="http://stackoverflow.com/"),
                                     notificationItem(text='linkB',href="http://stackoverflow.com/")
                                     )
        ),
        dashboardSidebar(),
        dashboardBody()
      )
    ), 
    server = function(input, output){}
  ), launch.browser = TRUE
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I saw a similar request about a year ago, but didn't look much deeper. This time I tried to get your code to work and couldn't then I looked at the `dropdownMenu` code and saw it simply wasn't setup to handle this, but could be modified to do so fairly easily.

I choose not to do that though, instead I created a new version of `dropdownMenu` specialized to do just this.

Here is the code:

```
library(shinydashboard)

dropdownHack <- function (...,badgeStatus = NULL, .list = NULL,menuname=NULL) 
{
  if (!is.null(badgeStatus)){
    shinydashboard:::validateStatus(badgeStatus)
  }
  items <- c(list(...), .list)
  lapply(items, shinydashboard:::tagAssert, type = "li")
  dropdownClass <- paste0("dropdown ", "text-menu")
  numItems <- length(items)
  if (is.null(badgeStatus)) {
    badge <- NULL
  }
  else {
    badge <- span(class = paste0("label label-", badgeStatus), numItems)
  }
  tags$li(class = dropdownClass, a( href="#", class="dropdown-toggle", 
                                    `data-toggle`="dropdown", menuname, badge),
          tags$ul(class = "dropdown-menu",  items  )
  )
}

menuitemHack <- function(text,href){
  notificationItem(text=text,href=href,icon=shiny::icon("rocket") )
}

runApp(
  shinyApp(
    ui = shinyUI(
      dashboardPage(
        dashboardHeader(title='Reporting Dashboard',
                        dropdownHack(menuname="GroupAB",
                                     menuitemHack(text='linkA',href="http://stackoverflow.com/"),
                                     menuitemHack(text='linkB',href="http://stackoverflow.com/")
                        ),
                        dropdownMenu(type='notifications',
                                   notificationItem(text='linkA',href="http://stackoverflow.com/"),
                                   notificationItem(text='linkB',href="http://stackoverflow.com/")
                        )
        ),
        dashboardSidebar(),
        dashboardBody()
      )
    ), 
    server = function(input, output){}
  ), launch.browser = TRUE
)
```

And here is the result:

[image]

Notes:

- It needs an icon, you can select any fontAwesome or Glyphicons, there is probably a blank one there somewhere if you want to have nothing.
- I imagine it will break if the ShinyDashboard structure changes much, so keep that in mind.
- Maybe the next version will support this option as well, it would just be a few lines of extra code.

Comment: Great! It works as expected, thank you very much.
Now the default settings of dropdown is a liitle too wide, and the link can not be open in a new window. I will search for some settings about it.

Comment: @Mike Wise can you help with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71857086/how-to-place-inputbuttons-in-the-header-of-r-shinydashboard-using-may-be-css-js

Comment: Haven't done any Shiny for a few years and kind of slammed on a robotics project at the moment. Sorry.