# How to place InputButtons in the Header of R shinydashboard (using may be CSS,JS,html)

Tags: javascript, css, r, shinydashboard

I have the below proto-type of my shiny app with two pages and two `selectInput` buttons in each page.

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Header",
                  dropdownMenuOutput("updatedTimeOutput"),
                  dropdownMenu(type = "notifications", 
                           badgeStatus = "warning",
                           icon = icon("bullhorn", "fa-lg"),
                           notificationItem(icon =  icon("bullhorn", "fa-1x"),
                                            status = "info",
                                            text = tags$span(
                                              tags$b("Please notice!")
                                            )
                           ))),

  dashboardSidebar( sidebarMenu(id = "tabs",
                                menuItem("Page1", tabName = "page1"),
                                menuItem("Page2", tabName = "page2"))),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(
        tabName = "page1",
    fluidRow(column(2,
      selectInput("count1", "Select a category", c("1", "2"))),
    column(2,selectInput("count2", "Select a subcategory1",       
                      c("cat1", "cat2", "cat3", "cat4")))),
      fluidRow(infoBoxOutput("ibox1")),
      fluidRow(valueBoxOutput("vbox1"))
    )
  ,
    tabItem(
      tabName = "page2",
      fluidRow(column(2,
        selectInput("count3", "Select a category", c("1", "2"))),
        column(2, selectInput("count4", "Select a subcategory2",       
                                   c("sub1", "sub2", "sub3", "sub4")))),
        fluidRow(infoBoxOutput("ibox2")),
        fluidRow(valueBoxOutput("vbox2")
      )
)
)
)
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  output$ibox1 <- renderInfoBox({
    infoBox(
      "Title",
      input$count1,
      icon = icon("credit-card")
    )
  })
  output$vbox1 <- renderValueBox({
    valueBox(
      "Title",
      input$count2,
      icon = icon("credit-card")
    )
  })
  output$ibox2 <- renderInfoBox({
    infoBox(
      "Title",
      input$count3,
      icon = icon("credit-card")
    )
  })
  output$vbox2 <- renderValueBox({
    valueBox(
      "Title",
      input$count4,
      icon = icon("credit-card")
    )
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

If the app is run, we will see two `selectInput` buttons in the body of each page. Is it possible to move the `selectInput` buttons in each page to the header so that it looks like:

page 1:

[image]

page 2:

[image]

The inputButtons should be placed in the header and should show the corresponding inputs of each page. Can someone help if it could be done in shiny application making use of any custom CSS or javascript or html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these CSS tricks, mobile friendly.

- When the screen is too small, automatically goes back to the tab.

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "Header"),
    dashboardSidebar( sidebarMenu(id = "tabs",
                                  menuItem("Page1", tabName = "page1"),
                                  menuItem("Page2", tabName = "page2"))),
    dashboardBody(
        tabItems(
            tabItem(
                tabName = "page1",
                fluidRow(class = "select-to-top", column(2,
                                selectInput("count1", "Select a category", c("1", "2"))),
                         column(2,selectInput("count2", "Select a subcategory1",       
                                              c("cat1", "cat2", "cat3", "cat4")))),
                fluidRow(infoBoxOutput("ibox1")),
                fluidRow(valueBoxOutput("vbox1"))
            )
            ,
            tabItem(
                tabName = "page2",
                fluidRow(class = "select-to-top", column(2,
                                selectInput("count3", "Select a category", c("1", "2"))),
                         column(2, selectInput("count4", "Select a subcategory2",       
                                               c("sub1", "sub2", "sub3", "sub4")))),
                fluidRow(infoBoxOutput("ibox2")),
                fluidRow(valueBoxOutput("vbox2")
                )
            )
        ),
        tags$style(HTML(
            "@media (min-width: 767px) {
                .select-to-top {
                    position: fixed; 
                    top: 0; 
                    left: 49%; 
                    width: 1000px;
                    z-index: 9999;
                }
                .main-header .logo {
                    height: 80px;
                }
                .left-side, .main-sidebar {
                    padding-top: 80px;
                }
            }
            "
        ))
    )
)


server <- function(input, output) {
    output$ibox1 <- renderInfoBox({
        infoBox(
            "Title",
            input$count1,
            icon = icon("credit-card")
        )
    })
    output$vbox1 <- renderValueBox({
        valueBox(
            "Title",
            input$count2,
            icon = icon("credit-card")
        )
    })
    output$ibox2 <- renderInfoBox({
        infoBox(
            "Title",
            input$count3,
            icon = icon("credit-card")
        )
    })
    output$vbox2 <- renderValueBox({
        valueBox(
            "Title",
            input$count4,
            icon = icon("credit-card")
        )
    })
    
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

#### Make input stays in header

##### Method 1

We fixed the header as well. When you scroll, the entire header is fixed on top. Change style to this

```r
        tags$style(HTML(
            "@media (min-width: 767px) {
                .select-to-top {
                    position: fixed; 
                    top: 0; 
                    left: 49%; 
                    width: 1000px;
                    z-index: 9999;
                }
                .main-header .logo {
                    height: 80px;
                    position: fixed;
                }
                .navbar.navbar-static-top {
                    position: fixed;
                    height: 80px;
                    width: 100%;
                }
                .left-side, .main-sidebar {
                    padding-top: 80px;
                }
                .content-wrapper {
                    padding-top: 80px;
                }
            }
            "
        ))
```

##### Method 2

Both input and header stay on top and don't move.

Use this style, just changed the position

```r
        tags$style(HTML(
            "@media (min-width: 767px) {
                .select-to-top {
                    position: absolute; 
                    top: 0; 
                    left: 49%; 
                    width: 1000px;
                    z-index: 9999;
                }
                .main-header .logo {
                    height: 80px;
                }
                .left-side, .main-sidebar {
                    padding-top: 80px;
                }
            }
            "
        ))
```

[image]

#### To work with dropdown

This code should make you work with dropdown menus.

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "Header", dropdownMenu(type = "messages", 
                                                   messageItem(from = "Sales Dept",message = "Sales are steady this month."))),
    dashboardSidebar( sidebarMenu(id = "tabs",
                                  menuItem("Page1", tabName = "page1"),
                                  menuItem("Page2", tabName = "page2"))),
    dashboardBody(
        tabItems(
            tabItem(
                tabName = "page1",
                fluidRow(class = "select-to-top", 
                         column(6, selectInput("count1", "Select a category", c("1", "2"))),
                         column(6,selectInput("count2", "Select a subcategory1", c("cat1", "cat2", "cat3", "cat4")))
                ),
                fluidRow(infoBoxOutput("ibox1")),
                fluidRow(valueBoxOutput("vbox1")),
                lapply(1:40, br)
            ),
            tabItem(
                tabName = "page2",
                fluidRow(class = "select-to-top", 
                         column(6,selectInput("count3", "Select a category", c("1", "2"))),
                         column(6, selectInput("count4", "Select a subcategory2", c("sub1", "sub2", "sub3", "sub4")))
                ),
                fluidRow(infoBoxOutput("ibox2")),
                fluidRow(valueBoxOutput("vbox2")
                )
            )
        ),
        tags$style(HTML(
            "@media (min-width: 767px) {
                .select-to-top {
                    position: absolute; 
                    top: 0; 
                    left: 50%; 
                    color: white;
                    transform: translateX(-45%);
                    width: 500px;
                    z-index: 9999;
                }
                .main-header .logo {
                    height: 60px;
                }
                .left-side, .main-sidebar {
                    padding-top: 60px;
                }
            }
            "
        ))
    )
)


server <- function(input, output) {
    output$ibox1 <- renderInfoBox({
        infoBox(
            "Title",
            input$count1,
            icon = icon("credit-card")
        )
    })
    output$vbox1 <- renderValueBox({
        valueBox(
            "Title",
            input$count2,
            icon = icon("credit-card")
        )
    })
    output$ibox2 <- renderInfoBox({
        infoBox(
            "Title",
            input$count3,
            icon = icon("credit-card")
        )
    })
    output$vbox2 <- renderValueBox({
        valueBox(
            "Title",
            input$count4,
            icon = icon("credit-card")
        )
    })
    
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: When the body has long content that has to be scrolled down the page, then the input buttons are also moving along. Can we make the input buttons stay in the header bar?

Comment: @DivadNojnarg  do u have a better solution using `shinydashboardplus`?

Comment: @chas See updates

Comment: Method 1 works as expected. However, `dropdownMenu` for notifications which was in the extreme right of my `dashboardheader` has disappeared.

Comment: There is no perfect solution, and you didn't mention notification dropdowns at all in your question. You can play with the CSS yourself or ask in another post.

Comment: indeed i had notifications in the actual app and did not mention it earlier as it wasn't expected that they will disappear after the solution. So i have modified the OP with them. Would be good to have an answer here instead of creating a new post. Anyways im accepting your solution.

Comment: @chas see edits for dropdown